# How to get two fingers scrolling on alienware?

Tags: laptop, touchpad

I would like to use two fingers scrolling on my M11x r3. So, I checked the control panel and I just had one finger scrolling.

I went to http://www.synaptics.com/en/drivers.php to update the drivers. I installed this driver and restarted the laptop. Now, I have v 15.2.8 and I don't have the two fingers scrolling.

What did I do wrong? Can synaptics touchpad on M11x work with two fingers?

Comment: Did you uninstall the previous drivers and reboot before installing the drivers from Synaptics?

Comment: Thanks for answering.
No, the previous drivers were installed when I bought the pc

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question. I didn't uninstall the previous one. should I ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading [these](http://drivers.synaptics.com/Synaptics_v16_2_21_C_XP32_Vista32_Win7-32_XP64_Vista64_Win7-64_Win8.zip) drivers from Synaptics' website. They are for Synaptics Gesture Suite and include multitouch functionality. If the driver doesn't work, make sure you have a mouse so you can rollback to your previous trackpad driver. The installer should check to ensure you have compatible drivers installed to install SGS, but it's always good to have a go-to position :).

If you'd like to know more about SGS click [here](http://www.synaptics.com/en/gesture-suite-windows.php)!

Cheers